# Args handling haskell

Tags: haskell, syntax

If my elemIndex is equal to Nothing let the default_value function be called.
There is my code :

```
import System.Environment
import System.Exit
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)
import Data.List (elemIndex)

default_value :: String -> Maybe Int
default_value elem
        | elem == "--rule" = 0
        | elem == "--start" = 0
        | elem == "--lines" = 0
        | elem == "--window" = 80
        | elem == "--move" = 0

getPos :: String -> [String] -> Maybe Int
getPos elem list = fromMaybe (default_value elem) (elemIndex elem list)

main :: IO ()
main = do
        args <- getArgs
        let rule = getPos "--rule" args
        let start = getPos "--start" args
        let lines = getPos "--lines" args
        let window = getPos "--window" args
        let move = getPos "--move" args
        putStrLn "Goumage"
```

When I compile I have this error and I don't understand it.

```
Compiling...
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( src/main.hs, src/main.o )

src/main.hs:11:51: error:
    parse error on input ‘=’
    Perhaps you need a 'let' in a 'do' block?
    e.g. 'let x = 5' instead of 'x = 5'
   |
11 | getPos elem list = elemIndex elem list == Nothing = default_value elem
   |                                                   ^
make: *** [Makefile:16: wolfram] Error 1
```

Comment: What is `getPos` supposed to do? It looks like you aim to make an `if` but without an `else`. But since Haskell works with expressions, that does not make much sense. Furthermore you will, given I understand it correctly, eventually get a type error for `default_value` since your `exitWith (...)` has type `IO` whereas the other guards result in an `Int` type.

Comment: You likely want to write `getPos elem list | ...`, but still you probably should use an `otherwise` guard.

Comment: The aim of `getPos` is to get the index of our parameter in the arguments list. For exemple if my list is `["--rule", "3"]` and i call `getPos "--rule"` it will returns the position of rule in my list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`elemIndex` already returns the index you want, wrapped in a `Just`, if the element is in the list. If it isn't, it returns `Nothing`.

By combining this with the [fromMaybe](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:fromMaybe) function you can easily supply the default for the case where it isn't found:

```
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)

-- more code here

getPos :: String -> [String] -> Int
getPos elem list = fromMaybe (default_value elem) (elemIndex elem list)
```

Note that this still won't compile because your `default_value` function needs to return a "plain" `Int`, not a `Maybe Int`. That's no problem here as all your values are in fact already "plain `Int`"s - just change the type signature and all should be well (if I haven't missed any other problems in your code).

Comment: `default_value` is partial, which isn't a compilation problem but will likely develop into a runtime problem; and of course `main`'s syntax is wrong too.

Comment: Thanks you, i understand my problem about the return values, however i still get an error :
`
Variable not in scope:
      elemIndex :: String -> [String] -> Maybe (Maybe Int)
   |
14 | getPos elem list = fromMaybe (default_value elem) (elemIndex elem list)
`

Comment: @Sanka, `elemIndex` needs to be `import`ed from `Data.List` (I forgot it wasn't in Prelude). As for what's wrong with `main`, I didn't spot it initially but there are two problems: a syntax error because you forgot the `do` at the start, and the fact that it doesn't actually do anything or return an `IO` value as it should, it just makes a bunch of `let` declarations.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I've edited my code above, did I follow your advice? Because I still have a problem at compile time. I'm not sure about the last line, I put it for the type of return be IO ().

Comment: I don't see any obvious mistakes (that would stop it compiling) - what's the new error? Oh, and please don't edit your question with my answer, now no-one can see the question I actually answered. If an answer to your question leads to a new one, leave the original question alone and either ask the new one in the comments (if it seems relatively small/simple) or post a completely new question.

Comment: Ok sorry my bad. My new error is : `src/main.hs:15:52: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Int’ with ‘Maybe Int’
      Expected type: Maybe (Maybe Int)
        Actual type: Maybe Int
    • In the second argument of ‘fromMaybe’, namely
        ‘(elemIndex elem list)’
      In the expression:
        fromMaybe (default_value elem) (elemIndex elem list)
      In an equation for ‘getPos’:
          getPos elem list
            = fromMaybe (default_value elem) (elemIndex elem list)
getPos elem list = fromMaybe (default_value elem) (elemIndex elem list)`

Comment: Oh sorry, my mistake - I hadn't corrected the type signature of `getPos`, it returns an `Int` not a `Maybe Int`. I've edited my answer to correct this.